# Swift & PHP: Retrieve/Get Object created by user/userid

Tags: object, get, parse-platform, swift, userid

How can I retrieve an object when I use userid on both platforms PHP and Swift ?

```
$url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TableClass/userid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes don't have inbuilt support for knowing the user that created them, you will need to add a column of type `Pointer<_User>`, probably call it `createdBy` then do a normal relational query.

References for doing relational queries:

- [Relational Queries using REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-relational) (for PHP)
- [Relational Queries using iOS API](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS) (for Swift)

Comment: They have Pointer<_User> when Swift makes new Class posted via userid pointer<_User>... I have the ID of the user how to search in TableClass for col userid pointer<_User> ?

Comment: Relational query is the way, as per the two links, it is covered quite well in the documentation